# Run a python spark job in yarn-cluster mode

Tags: python, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

Here comes a problem when I use spark run pi.py script in example of spark python, when I use yarn-client mode, everything works fine. But when I use yarn-cluster mode, the job can't start, and the container return a syntax error like this:

LogType:stdout

Log Upload Time:Thu May 21 08:48:16 +0800 2015

LogLength:111

Log Contents:

File "pi.py", line 40

```
return 1 if x ** 2 + y ** 2 < 1 else 0
```

I'm sure the script is right, Can anybody help me out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Noticed that syntax error is feature included in new version of Python, so I thought that maybe this is a problem about the Python version which Spark is using.

I added a property in

```
/etc/spark/conf.cloudera.spark_on_yarn/spark-defaults.conf:
spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.PYSPARK_PYTHON
```

to specify the Python binary path.

Answer (score 1):

spark doesn't currently support running python scripts in cluster mode (deploying the driver to the cluster)

> Alternatively, if your application is submitted from a machine far
>   from the worker machines (e.g. locally on your laptop), it is common
>   to use cluster mode to minimize network latency between the drivers
>   and the executors. Note that cluster mode is currently not supported
>   for Mesos clusters or Python applications.

https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.3.1/submitting-applications.html